# Cucumber feature file not executing from Maven

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, cucumber, junit5

I'm trying to execute my `cucumber` `feature` file using maven command `mvn clean install` but it's not picking my Test class. I'm able to run the feature file using my IDE IntelliJ but not working from command line. Please find my code and maven dependencies.

What I'm missing here, why mvn clean install not picking the `RunTest` and executing the step definitions from here `MyStepdefs`.

Any help would be really appreciated, I've been struggling from past two days - not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            cucumber.plugin=pretty,html:target/cucumber.html
                            cucumber.publish.quiet=true
                            cucumber.publish.enabled=false
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**test.feature**

```
Feature: To retrieve the customer with customer details

  Scenario: retrieve the customer with customer id
    Given the customer saved with customer name "john" and customer id 100
    When the client calls GET "/customer/{customerId}" with customer id as 100
```

**RunTest.java**

```
import io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Cucumber;
    
    @Cucumber
    public class RunTest {
        
    }
```

**MyStepdefs.java**

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class MyStepdefs {
    @Given("the customer saved with customer name {string} and customer id {int}")
    public void the_customer_saved_with_customer_name_and_customer_id(String string, Integer int1) {
        System.out.println("Entering into given");
    }

    @When("the client calls GET {string} with customer id as {int}")
    public void the_client_calls_get_with_customer_id_as(String string, Integer int1) {
        System.out.println("Entering into when");
    }

}
```

**CucumberSpringConfig.java**

```
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;


@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class)
public class CucumberSpringConfig {
}
```

This is my folder structure:
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Mdc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#use-the-cucumber-annotation

> Cucumber will scan the package of a class annotated with `@Cucumber` for feature files.
> To use this feature, add the `@Cucumber` annotation to the test runner. Doing so will make Cucumber run the feature files in the package containing the test runner.

So because your annotated class is in the `com.example.demo` package  put the features in `src/test/resources/com/example/demo`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, is there any option to configure where our feature file is located? Something like this @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features") I tried this but @CucumberOptions not working. Please suggest if any alternative is there. Thanks again!